# How to avoid overflow using \IEEEpubid on the first column?

Tags: two-column, ieeetran

I am trying to write a **journal** paper using the **IEEEtran.cls** template.

My problem is that the **Publication ID Mark overflows** into my thanks section.

This is the bottom of the title page:

[image]

From the documentation of **IEEEtran.cls** we see that:

[image]

I included the command `\IEEEpubidadjcol` into the second column. This prevents the overflow in the second column as you can see in my previous image, but lets the first column run freely.

I tried including `\IEEEpubidadjcol` into the first column aswell, but that causes compilation errors.

Please, could you give me some hint on how to solve this problem without doing something illegal with respect to the IEEE modus operandi?

EDIT:

As the answer suggests, the problem can be solved using the `\IEEEpubidadjcol` command **twice**. When I tried this, I got an error:

```
Infinite glue shrinkage found in box being split
```

In spite of this error a correct pdf is produced. The error goes away when I **do not** include packages **fixltx2e** and **dblfloatfix**.

Comment: Can you show a minimal example of code?

Comment: @egreg There is a lot of text needed, so I used pastebin.http://pastebin.com/d4Xyu3d6

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Contrary to what the documentation says, it seems that `\IEEEpubidadjcol` has to be issued also in the first column.

```
\documentclass[journal, a4paper]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\title{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit}

\author{Martin Drozdik%
  \thanks{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam eleifend
    orci eros, ac volutpat mauris molestie at. Sed auctor, diam eu tempor blandit}%
  \thanks{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam eleifend
    orci eros, ac volutpat mauris molestie at. Sed auctor, diam eu tempor blandit}%
}

\markboth{IEEE Transactions on Evolutionary Computation}{}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\IEEEpubid{0000--0000/00\$00.00 \copyright\ 2013 IEEE}

\lipsum[1-2]

\IEEEpubidadjcol

\lipsum[3-7]

\IEEEpubidadjcol

\lipsum[8-12]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately if I try this I get an `Infinite glue shrinkage found in box being split` error message. But I think this is a separate issue that I need to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\title{Cryptanalyzing Fridrich's chaotic image encryption scheme}

\author{Li Drozdik%
  \thanks{D. Li is with College of Information Engineering, Xiangtan University, Xiangtan 411105, Hunan, China.}%
  \thanks{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam eleifend
    orci eros, ac volutpat mauris molestie at. Sed auctor, diam eu tempor blandit}%
}

\markboth{IEEE Transactions on Evolutionary Computation}{}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

%\IEEEpubid{0000--0000/00\$00.00 \copyright\ 2013 IEEE}

\IEEEpubid{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\ \\[12pt] \centering
  1551-3203 \copyright 2015 IEEE. Personal use is permitted, but republication/redistribution requires IEEE permission.\\
  See http://www.ieee.org/publications standards/publications/rights/index.html for more information.
\end{minipage}}

\lipsum[1-2]

\IEEEpubidadjcol

\lipsum[3-7]

\IEEEpubidadjcol

%  must call \IEEEpubidadjcol in the second column for its text to clear the %IEEEpubid mark.

\lipsum[8]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem with declaring \IEEEpubidadjcol in the second column only. However, I found that the error "Infinite glue shrinkage found in box being split" is due to the use of "\usepackage{fixltx2e}". Removing it resolved the error.

Comment: [`fixltx2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fixltx2e) is considered obsolete as it has been included in the LaTeX kernel since its 2015 release. Related: [How to use `fixltx2e` only when necessary](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/287146/5764)