# IEEE Transactions copyright

Tags: ieeetran, ieee-style

What is the command to write the copyright "@2015 IEEE. Personal use is permitted, but republication/redistribution requires IEEE permission."
on the bottom center of the first page?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You can use `\ieeepubid` to display publication IDs and copyright notices. [This answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146232/65692) includes an example how to use that.

Comment: Thanks, one more question. The copyright requires two lines, The second line is "See http://www.ieee.org ... for more information." How would I do this?

Comment: Did you try the code i mentioned?

Comment: A solution using TikZ is provided at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/279794/9075.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it as follows:

```
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\IEEEpubid{\makebox[\columnwidth]{978-2-5299-5611-2/10/\$25.00 \copyright 2015 IEEE \hfill} \hspace{\columnsep}\makebox[\columnwidth]{ }}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
\maketitle
%.......
\IEEEpubid{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\ \\[12pt] \centering
  1551-3203 \copyright 2015 IEEE. Personal use is permitted, but republication/redistribution requires IEEE permission.\\
  See http://www.ieee.org/publications standards/publications/rights/index.html for more information.
\end{minipage}} 
%.......
\begin{abstract}
```

Call `\IEEEpubidadjcol` in the second column for its text to clear the IEEEpubid mark.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Code may be displayed by indenting it by 4 spaces.  Alternatively mark the code with you mouse and then click on the `{}` icon above the text entry box.

Comment: where does the minipage `\begin` ?