# IEEE Transactions copyright 2

Tags: ieeetran, ieee-style

As an extension to my question here [IEEE Transactions copyright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279769/ieee-transactions-copyright)
which has been resolved, I have a follow-up question.

The \IEEEpubid works to input @2015 IEEE. Personal use is permitted, but republication/redistribution requires IEEE permission.

But I also need a line below that also centered which will say "See http://www.ieee.org/publications standards/publications/rights/index.html for more information."

An example of what I am talking about is this http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=7116675

How would I do that? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried my code?

Comment: Similar questions: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/279769/9075 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/279131/9075

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example using TikZ:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\copyrighttext{%
  \footnotesize 1551-3203 © 2015 IEEE. Personal use is permitted, but republication/redistribution requires IEEE permission.
See http://www.ieee.org/publications_standards/publications/rights/index.html for more information.}

\newcommand\copyrightnotice{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=south,yshift=10pt] at (current page.south) {\fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-\fboxsep-\fboxrule\relax}{\copyrighttext}}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\copyrightnotice
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

The other way to do is :

```
\IEEEpubid{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\ \\[12pt]
  1551-3203 © 2015 IEEE.\\
 Personal use is permitted, but republication/redistribution requires IEEE permission.
\end{minipage}}
```